# Get S3 bucket size from aws GO SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 bucket to upload files (using GO SDK). I have a requirement to charge client when their directory size exceeds 2GB.

The directory hierarchy inside bucket is like: `/BUCKET/uploads/CLIENTID/yyyy/mm/dd`

For this, I have searched a lot about it. But could not find anything.

How can I get the directory size inside a bucket using SDK ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `/uploads/CLIENTID/yyyy/mm/dd` is not a directory in S3 bucket, but a [prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html). The S3 management UI in AWS Console may trick you to think a bucket has subdirectories, just like your computer file system, but they are prefixes.

Your question really is: How can I get the total size of all objects inside a bucket, with a given prefix?

Hope this code snippet can clear your doubts.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

// iterate all objects in a given S3 bucket and prefix, sum up objects' total size in bytes
// use: size, err := S3ObjectsSize("example-bucket-name", "/a/b/c")
func S3ObjectsSize(bucket string, prefix string, s3client S3Client) (int64, error) {
    output, err := s3client.ListObjectsV2(context.TODO(), &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Prefix: aws.String(prefix),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return -1, fmt.Errorf("cannot ListObjectsV2 in %s/%s: %s", bucket, prefix, err.Error())
    }

    var size int64
    for _, object := range output.Contents {
        size += object.Size
    }

    return size, nil

}

// stub of s3.Client for dependency injection
type S3Client interface {
    ListObjectsV2(ctx context.Context, params *s3.ListObjectsV2Input, optFns ...func(*s3.Options)) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error)
}
```

Comment: will it cost me on AWS to calculate size with this method ?

Comment: Also the code does not compile. gives me error of unmatched number of arguments.

Comment: I believe LIST operation incurs a cost (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/#:~:text=Objects%20stored%20for%2030%20days,30%2Dday%20minimum%20request%20charge.&text=For%20each%20object%20that%20is,or%20S3%20Deep%20Archive%20rates.), free-tier applies.

Comment: the code snippet is to demonstrate which S3 API to use, I didn't run it with any AWS credentials. note: the code uses AWS Go SDK V2.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating on listing objects. However the code runs successfully but gives access denied error. I have checked the region & bucket owner permissions. Owner is allowed to list objects by default. How should I check this ?

Comment: in which environment did you run the code? if you run the code from your local machine, please make sure your CLI has correct AWS permission. try some basic AWS cli command such as `aws s3 ls` to see if you can get the correct buckets.